# DIV 100% width and height of parent

Tags: html, css

I have this markup:

```
<div>
     <div class="inner"></div
     <img src="blabla" />
</div>
```

How to make `.inner` 100% width and 100% height of its parent div dimensions? Parent div's dimensions rely on `img` dimensions.

Is it possible to do this with CSS? I don't want JS solution as it's obvious. Thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/7cSzV/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/vSE7S/2/

CSS

```
.outer { position: relative; }
.inner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    background: black;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
img { display: block }
```

(I just gave an `.outer` class to the outer div, for the sake of the simplicity)

note: try also to assign `display: inline-block` to the outer div: the resulting effect is slightly different, see http://jsfiddle.net/vSE7S/3/ — just choose the effect that fits best to your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, however it has 100% width of the page, not the image: http://jsfiddle.net/vSE7S/4/

Comment: don't we need to set the height `100%` to all parent containers?

Answer (score 0):

You might change the css and add a class to that parent div

```
.inner {
    background: black;
    /* position: absolute; */
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    /*width: 100px;
    height: 100px;*/
}
div.parentDiv{
    position: relative;
}
```